# No database selected: login php code

Tags: php, authentication

```
<?php
    session_start();
        $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","xxx","xxxxxx","xxx");
            if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
            {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
            }


        $eadd = $_POST['eadd'];
        $pass = $_POST['pass'];
        $eadd = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes(strip_tags($eadd)));
        $pass = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes(strip_tags($pass)));
        if (filter_var($eadd, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE Emailadd = '$eadd' AND Password = '$pass'");
            if(!$sql){
                die('There was an error in query '. mysql_error());
                }
            $count = mysql_numrows($sql) or die(mysql_error());
            if ($count<=0)
                {

                    echo "
                        <html>
                            <style>
                                body{
                                    background-color:#cccccc;
                                    }
                                #error{
                                    position:relative;
                                    margin:auto;
                                    top:20px;
                                    width:320px;
                                    height:55px;
                                    background-color:#63a8d7;
                                    border:1px  solid #2a262a;
                                    }

                                #errorC{
                                    position:absolute;
                                    top:20px;
                                    left:20px;
                                    font: 14px arial, tahoma;
                                    }
                            </style>
                            <body>
                                <div id=error>
                                    <div id=errorC>
                                        Incorrect Email Address and Password! <a href=index.php>GO BACK</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </body>
                        </html>
                            ";
                }
                else
                {
                    //have them logged in
                    $_SESSION['account'] = $eadd;
                    header('location:home.php');
                }
                mysqli_close($con);
        } else {
            echo "
                <html>
                    <style>
                        body{
                            background-color:#cccccc;
                            }
                        #error{
                            position:relative;
                            margin:auto;
                            top:20px;
                            width:320px;
                            height:55px;
                            background-color:#63a8d7;
                            border:1px  solid #2a262a;
                            }

                        #errorC{
                            position:absolute;
                            top:20px;
                            left:20px;
                            font: 14px arial, tahoma;
                            }
                    </style>
                    <body>
                        <div id=error>
                            <div id=errorC>
                                Invalid Email Address! <a href=index.php>GO BACK</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </body>
                </html>
                    ";
        }
?>
```

Why there is an error "No database selected"? My mysqli_connect is correct. I have another register php code, using which I can register some email address using that connection.But here in login php code, I can't login with the user email address.

Comment: You need to select the database you're working with - http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php

Comment: mysqli_select_db($con, "xxx"); i add this line of code but still not working

Comment: @DieejayPeke Either use mysqli_* or mysql_*. I have used mysql in my answer and in my sample code too. You can try the same too.

Comment: What happens when executing `mysqli_select_db($con, "xxx");`?

Comment: Don't store passwords in plaintext! Also, look into MySQLi bind variables.

Comment: thanks dcoder for your comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the above code its look like you are using `mysqli_connect` for database connection and `mysql_query` for query execution. Use `mysqli_query` instead of `mysql_query` . Like this

```
mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE Emailadd = '$eadd' AND Password = '$pass'");
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you need to select a database after authentication.
We need to follow these steps while making a database connection.

1. Create a connection
2. Select the database
3. Fire the query
4. Use query result
5. Close the connection

[Sample Code is here](https://bitbucket.org/blunderboy/sandbox/src/523aebe74b729a73d50062301eaf81169f26abda/php/basic/14_db_interaction.php?at=master)

Firstly, You need to add this line in your code after login

```
$db_select = mysql_select_db("myDatabase", $con);
```

Secondly, you need to pass `$con` as second parameter after selecting your database So your query statement becomes like this

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE Emailadd = '$eadd' AND Password = '$pass'", $con);
```